# Why does this give value n^n if I'm just doing n^2?

Tags: java

I am doing a problem in Hackerrank and I got the testcases wrong. After inserting System.out.println commands here and there I finally found out whats wrong with the code:

It was in the while loop. I removed complexities from the while loop and executed a basic loop in my local eclipse environment and the result was same:

This is the code:

```
    int n=3;
        
        while(n<100)
        {
            System.out.println(n+" n WHILE");
                n=n*n;
            System.out.println(n*n+" n n WHILE");
        }
```

---

My understanding was that that n would initialize to n*n, instead it's being initialized to n^n.
The output is as follows:

```
3 n WHILE
81 n n WHILE
9 n WHILE
6561 n n WHILE
81 n WHILE
43046721 n n WHILE
```

---

### Ok, I thought maybe some initialization problem or something and I modified the code as follows and its still the printing the same output.

```
    while(n<100)
        {
            System.out.println(n+" n WHILE");
            n=(int) Math.pow(n, 2);
            System.out.println(n*n+" n n WHILE");
        }
```

The above code has same output too. Now, I know I can add a duplicate variable to initialize properly but my question is why do the above implementations fail? Also, is keeping a duplicate variable my only workaround? What's the proper way to do that?

PS: Incase you're wondering the hackerrank problem link and my solution, I'll just give a pastebin link instead to lengthening this already large question.
Link = [Link](https://pastebin.com/qXxWXKim)

Comment: `System.out.println(n*n+" n n WHILE");` should be `System.out.println(n+" n n WHILE");`

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking. You get the value of `n^2`, set it to `n`, and raise the new `n` to the power of 2. You're printing the *new* value of `n` * n in your println, making it look like you're doing the operation twice, even though `n` isn't being altered the second time.

Comment: Your Calc is fine. The debug prints are buggy.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand the question.  It would really help if you could post your expected output.  All I see right now is the actual output of the program, which is exactly what I would expect your code to do.  We need to know what **you** want the program to do differently in order to help you.

Comment: Nothing is buggy here. Both the calculation and the console output is correct in terms of programming. As @DaveNewton told, you do the multiplication operation twice. First you multiply at the line n=n x n; So at the first step of the while loop n equals 9 after this line. Then when you want to print to the console you multiply n again with itself            
System.out.println(n x n+" n n WHILE");
Therefore it prints out 9 x 9 which is equal to 81 at the first step of the while loop. But n is still 9 because you didn't assign the result of the multiplication to n. Fine?

Comment: N is getting initialized with n*n, you are simply outputting another n*n when doing system.out.println.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Sorry, the previous link was broken. See the link in question now and you'll know the details :)

Comment: Also, to everyone, yeah, I'm sorry. I somehow completely missed that I am printing n*n in debug print statements.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I edited the code now but I'm still having problems with testcases, could you tell me whats wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1):

The question code does not calculate `n ^ n` anywhere, but the way you print makes the output very confusing, because you're print `n*n` *after* already updating `n`, so you're actually printing `n ^ 4`.

Here is a better version of the `print` statements:

```java
int n = 3;
while (n < 100) {
    System.out.println("n = " + n + "  ->  " + n + " * " + n + " = " + n * n);
    n = n * n;
}
System.out.println("n = " + n);
```

*Output*

```
n = 3  ->  3 * 3 = 9
n = 9  ->  9 * 9 = 81
n = 81  ->  81 * 81 = 6561
n = 6561
```

What you are calculating is `n ^ (2 ^ i)` where `i` is the number of iterations of the loop, i.e.

- After 1 iteration: n = n * n = n<sup>2</sup>   *(3<sup>2</sup> = 9)*
- After 2 iterations: n = (n * n) * (n * n) = n<sup>4</sup>   *(3<sup>4</sup> = 81)*
- After 3 iterations: n = ((n * n) * (n * n)) * ((n * n) * (n * n)) = n<sup>8</sup>   *(3<sup>8</sup> = 6561)*
- After 4 iterations: n = n<sup>16</sup>   *(3<sup>16</sup> = 43,046,721)*
- After 5 iterations: n = n<sup>32</sup>   *(3<sup>32</sup> = 1,853,020,188,851,841)*
- After 6 iterations: n = n<sup>64</sup>   *(3<sup>64</sup> = 3,433,683,820,292,512,484,657,849,089,281)*
- ...

That is a far cry from `n ^ (i + 1)`, which might have been what you expected?

- After 1 iteration: n = n * n = n<sup>2</sup>   *(3<sup>2</sup> = 9)*
- After 2 iterations: n = n * n * n = n<sup>3</sup>   *(3<sup>3</sup> = 27)*
- After 3 iterations: n = n * n * n * n = n<sup>4</sup>   *(3<sup>4</sup> = 81)*
- After 4 iterations: n = n * n * n * n * n = n<sup>5</sup>   *(3<sup>5</sup> = 243)*
- After 5 iterations: n = n * n * n * n * n * n = n<sup>6</sup>   *(3<sup>6</sup> = 729)*
- After 6 iterations: n = n * n * n * n * n * n * n = n<sup>7</sup>   *(3<sup>7</sup> = 2187)*
- ...

To do that, you need a separate result variable:

```java
int n = 3;
int r = n;
while (r < 100) {
    System.out.println("r = " + r + "  ->  " + r + " * " + n + " = " + r * n);
    r = r * n;
}
System.out.println("r = " + r);
```

*Output*

```
r = 3  ->  3 * 3 = 9
r = 9  ->  9 * 3 = 27
r = 27  ->  27 * 3 = 81
r = 81  ->  81 * 3 = 243
r = 243
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `System.out.println(n*n+" n n WHILE");` prints the square of the current value of n.

If you remove this line, the output will make an awful lot more sense.

You are currently printing n, squaring n, and then printing the square of the new n (without squaring n a second time).

The lines ending in "n WHILE" start at 3 and keep squaring. They show the value of n.

The lines ending in "n n WHILE" start at 9 (3 squared) and keep squaring. They show the square of the value of n.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are setting n (n1) to **3**. Then print it.
2. Next, you are setting n (n2) to `n*n` (`n1*n1`) and then print n*n (`n2*n2`) in the second print statement. Using the notion n1,n2 you print `n2*n2 = (n1*n1)*(n1*n1)` = n1^4 which is **81**.

Next loop prints 9^2 and 9^4.

Answer (score 0):

The way you were printing the new value made no sense. You initialized n to n^2 and than did another n^2 on that in your print either of these would work.

```
 while(n<100)
 {
       System.out.println(n+" n WHILE");
       n=n*n;
       System.out.println(n+" n n WHILE");
 }

 while(n<100)
 {
      System.out.println(n+" n WHILE");
      System.out.println(n*n+" n n WHILE");
      n=n*n;         
 }
```